# How can I POST all the clicked buttons on a page?

Tags: php, post, button

I have a page in where users can ask questions.
When they move on to the next page, I need to do a mysql query and post all the asked question into the database. I use jquery to hide the answers and show them when clicking the corresponding button.

The structure of the page looks like this:

```
<!-- questions.php -->

<form action="submitquestions.php" method="post">
   <div>
      <span>This is a question</span>
      <button name="question" value="question1">Ask the question</button>
      <span>This is the answer</span>
   </div>
   <div>
      <span>This is a question</span>
      <button name="question" value="question2">Ask the question</button>
      <span>This is the answer</span>
   </div>
   <div>
   ....
   </div>
   <button name="submit">Go to the next page</button>
</form>

<!-- submitquestions.php -->
<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        var_dump($_POST);

} ?>
```

How can I put all the clicked buttons into the $_POST array and that way submit the data to my database?

Comment: Do you need to collect the responses of each question? If so, how are you collecting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
<form action="submitquestions.php" method="post">
   <div>
      <span>This is a question</span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="question[]" value="question1" style="display:none">
      <button>Ask the question</button>
      <span>This is the answer</span>
   </div>
   <div>
      <span>This is a question</span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="question[]" value="question2" style="display:none">
      <button>Ask the question</button>
      <span>This is the answer</span>
   </div>
   <div>
   ....
   </div>
   <button name="submit">Go to the next page</button>
</form>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("form button").click(function(){
       $(this).prev(":checkbox").attr("checked", true);
    });
  });
</script>

<!-- submitquestions.php -->
<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(!isset($_POST['question'])) $_POST['question'] = array(); //Just in the case no button is pressed
    //$_POST['question'] will have an array of all clicked questions.
    var_dump($_POST);

} ?>
```

As you can see, we use 'hidden' checkboxes 'behind' each button, that check when a button is pressed. And, as our buttons don't have name but checkboxes do, we send only the checked checkboxes to the server.

`$_POST['question']` will have an array of all clicked questions. No 'isset' per question needed

Comment: About the "*No 'isset' per question needed*" part - what if user does not check any checkbox?

Comment: @binaryLV won't need isset per question, but isset per array just in case. I'll edit it to make it more clear, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Considered using checkboxes? You could style them nicely with jQuery as well. You really shouldn't use `<button>`s anyway.

Simply use `<input type="checkbox" name="question1">` then the [jQueryUI buttons and checkboxes](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#checkbox) to style it. Make sure your disable it once it has been checked so it doesn't get undone.

Then in PHP, check `if(isset($_POST['question1'] )) {` to see if a box has been checked.

Thanks for feedback from comments.

Comment: About `$_POST['question1'] == 'on'` - I would use `isset($_POST['question1'])`.

Comment: This solution will be a problem if a button is clicked more than once though. Using some js to disable them after the first click could be a workaround for that. I also agree with binaryLV about using isset, way better solution than checking if it's value is 'on'

Comment: good solution :) that would've worked too!
thanks for the help dunham

Answer (score 0):

If you use `<button type="submit" name="this button's unique name goes here" value="1">Button text goes here</button>` then you can check for the button that triggered the submit with `$_POST ['this button's unique name goes here'] == 1`

At least in theory you can.  Internet Explorer prior to version 8 mishandles the `<button>` tag quite badly.  In internet explorer 6 it is in fact basically impossible to determine which button was clicked if you use the `<button>` tag.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp